# sanic.exceptions.MethodNotSupported: Method GET not allowed for URL /model/parse

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-405, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am working on a rasa chatbot. For training the chatbot, I added all the training data to the `nlu.md` file. I added the stories to the `stories.md` file. I configured the `domain.yml` file and I also created a few custom actions that the bot should run when the user asks a particular question. Now I trained the chatbot using the rasa train command. This created a zipped file inside the models folder.

I started the NLU server with the following command

```
rasa run --enable-api -m models/nlu-20190919-171124.tar.gz
```

For the front end, I am using django to create a web appication for the chatbot.

This is the `index.html` file

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

When the user types a message in the input area and clicks send, this view should run

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_message = request.POST['message']
        response = requests.get("http://localhost:5005/model/parse",params={"q":user_message})
        print(response)
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But when I click the send button, I get a `405 error`. This is the complete error message from the NLU-server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 893, in handle_request
    handler, args, kwargs, uri = self.router.get(request)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/router.py", line 407, in get
    return self._get(request.path, request.method, "")
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/router.py", line 446, in _get
    raise method_not_supported
sanic.exceptions.MethodNotSupported: Method GET not allowed for URL /model/parse
```

This is the message from my django server.

```
<Response [405]>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am following the steps indicated in the **[rasa documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/using-nlu-only/)**.

Comment: You are calling get here `response = requests.get("http://localhost:5005/model/parse",params={"q":user_message})
` have you defined route for it

Comment: I dont think so. Can you tell me how to do it pease?